# Issue with PPT conversion using python-Django

Tags: django, python, django-views, document-conversion

I was just trying to convert a PPT using the following URL http://code.google.com/p/qifei/wiki/PDFConverter python code

I could see the same thing happening with the command line option too

python documentconverter.py /home/rajeev/Desktop/Downloads/Industry2.ppt /home/rajeev/Desktop/test.pdf

It appears that the image overlaps on some text in some cases.Are there any work arounds for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mangled images are probably a function of the pdf converter (in this case, Open Office). Try using a different library like [pyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/).